# Link going to different url

Tags: hyperlink, html, facebook-wall

When I share a link form my blog to facebook it goes to a totally different url, it only happens when the link is posted on facebook.

Comment: We're gonna need more information.  Can you give us some code? What is the link?  How are you adding it?  What does this have to do with spans?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a usage question? If the latter, this is probably off-topic.

Comment: Two scenarios: 1) your og:URL tags are wrong
2) your website has been hacked, but only referred traffic gets the hacked version - i've seen this before, you can check this by manually making a HTTP request to your server with facebook.com as the referrer

Answer (score 0):

Igy is right consider checking the following in cURL

`curl -i http://yourdomain.com -e https://facebook.com`

option `e` sends the "Referer Page" information to the HTTP server.